# Flatten a Map<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>> into a Vec<u8> and then return it to a Map<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>

Tags: vector, rust, hashmap, bytebuffer

I've have data in a `HashMap<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>` and I want to write that data to a file as a byte buffer (a single `Vec<u8>`) and then read it back from the file and reconstruct the `HashMap` structure.

Is there an established algorithm for flattening and recovering maps like this? I could write metadata into the file to distinguish where the data partitions etc.  I can't use structured serialization because of the nature of this project — I am encrypting the data and the file.

Comment: Is there any problem with simply writing `(V, V)` where `V` is pair `(len, bytes)`?

Comment: Considered doing something like that but not too keen on using tuples to solve this issue.      If I say took hashmap and filtered both the keys and the values into a `Vec<(u8, Vec<u8>)>` where in the first value is the len and the 2nd is the byte list, it still makes it difficult to know which item was a key and which was a value.

Comment: You may store it consequentially value always after its key, let me just show it

Comment: sure, would appreciate that.

Comment: It can be argued that flattening a hashmap to a file **is** serialization regardless of the format. So you may want to clarify what you can and cannot use. For example, using serde, you could serialize your data into JSON, and then encrypt the resulting string and write it into a file.

Comment: Should have added a bit of clarification.  When I said I couldn't use serialization I meant that I couldn't use a structured format like Json.  The idea is for the file to be completely unrecoverable without the appropriate password and key. Feels like adding a bit of structure would make a easier to decrypt.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused here. Whatever textual or binary format you choose can be written into an `io::Write` stream, which in turn could be piped into an encrypted file using something like https://docs.rs/cryptostream/0.3.1/cryptostream/

Comment: Sorry, I can't really describe the problem too well since its kind of proprietary still.  Suffice to say that its been solved via the answer below and bincode. cryptostream probably would work as well and I am already using sodiumoxide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store this with the following format:

`value1_len | value1_bytes | key1_len | key1_bytes | value2_len | value2_bytes | key2_len | key2_bytes | ...`

what can be fairly easily done with the standard library ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77952de52fe4d38e3c5d7f42ae946389)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn serialize(map: &HashMap<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
    map.iter().fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, (k, v)| {
        acc.extend(&k.len().to_le_bytes());
        acc.extend(k.as_slice());
        acc.extend(&v.len().to_le_bytes());
        acc.extend(v.as_slice());
        acc
    })
}

fn read_vec(input: &mut &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let (len, rest) = input.split_at(std::mem::size_of::<usize>());
    let len = usize::from_le_bytes(len.try_into().unwrap());
    let (v, rest) = rest.split_at(len);
    *input = rest;
    v.to_vec()
}

fn deserialize(bytes: &Vec<u8>) -> HashMap<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    let mut left = &bytes[..];
    while left.len() > 0 {
        let k = read_vec(&mut left);
        let v = read_vec(&mut left);
        map.insert(k, v);
    }

    map
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6]);
    map.insert(vec![4, 5, 6], vec![1, 2, 3]);
    map.insert(vec![1, 5, 3], vec![4, 2, 6]);

    let array = serialize(&map);
    let recovered_map = deserialize(&array);

    assert_eq!(map, recovered_map);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using bincode but I like your solution.  I may still use a variation of it and just add it as an optional API.